# python math operations on list contents before output.write

Tags: python, math, csv, output

I will put here a code with two endings, one that works, another that doesn't.

*I won't emphasize on what the purpose of the code is, since it is not the problem here...*

**The difference between my two endings** is that in the second solution (that crashes), I wanted
to apply some modification of the data.

Here's the beginning of the code which is commons to the two `.py` files:

```
import tetgen, geometry
from pprint import pprint
import random, csv
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

all_colors = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for name, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('colors.csv'))]

priority_list = {name: int(i)
                 for i, name in csv.reader(open('priority.csv'))}

# background is marked SUPPORT
support_i = [i for i, color in enumerate(all_colors) if color[0] == 'SUPPORT']
if len(support_i)>0:
    support = np.array(all_colors[support_i[0]][1:])
    del all_colors[support_i[0]]
else:
    support = None

tg, hull_i = geometry.tetgen_of_hull([(X,Y,Z) for name, X, Y, Z in all_colors])
colors = [all_colors[i] for i in hull_i]

print ("thrown out: "
       + ", ".join(set(zip(*all_colors)[0]).difference(zip(*colors)[0])))

targets = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z), float(BG))
           for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))]

for target in targets:
    name, X, Y, Z, BG = target
    target_point = support + (np.array([X,Y,Z]) - support)/(1-BG)
    tet_i, bcoords = geometry.containing_tet(tg, target_point)
    AT = (1-BG)
```

After this, the solution (let's call it (1)) works:

```
    output = open('solution_AT.txt','a')

    if tet_i == None:
        output.write(str(target[0]))
        output.write('\n')

    else:
        names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
        sorted_indices = sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name])
        output.write(target[0])
        counting = 0

        for i, name in sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name]):
            output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bcoords[i]*AT))
            counting = counting + 1

            if counting > 3:
                output.write('\n')
                counting = 0

output.close()
```

but not the solution (2):

```
    output = open('solution_AT.txt','a')

    if tet_i == None:
        output.write(str(target[0]))
        output.write('\n')

    else:
        names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
        sorted_indices = sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name])
        output.write(target[0])
        counting = 0

        for i, name in sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name]):
            counting = counting + 1
            top = bcoords[i]*AT
            output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, top))

            if counting > 0:
                counting = counting + 1
                cheese = bcoords[i]*AT
                output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, cheese/(1-top)))

                if counting > 1:
                    counting = counting + 1
                    meat = bcoords[i]*AT
                    output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, meat/(1-top-cheese)))    

                    if counting > 2:
                        counting = counting + 1
                        bread = bcoords[i]*AT
                        output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bread/(1-top-cheese-meat))

                        if counting > 3:
                            output.write('\n')
                            counting = 0

output.close()
```

I am getting the error: `Failed to run script - syntax error - invalid syntax` and the pointer says it's there (where I put "|") : `if counting > |3:`

Do you have any idea why??

As you can see, what I am trying to do is to apply these **"top/cheese/meat"** formulae to `bcoords[i]`, see below:

**pseudocode:**

```
if counting = 0   // this is the initial value
I want: 
- top = bcoords[i]*AT
- counting = 1

if counting = 1   // the next value...
- cheese = bcoords[i]*AT
- output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, cheese/(1-top))
- counting = 2

if counting = 2
- meat = bcoords[i]*AT
- output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, meat/(1-top-cheese))    
- counting = 3

if counting > 2:
- counting = counting + 1
- bread = bcoords[i]*AT
- output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bread/(1-top-cheese-meat))
```

But it doesn't works AT ALL!

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a traceback/error message?

Comment: the script fails to run: `Failed to run script: syntax error -invalid syntax` and it stops there (where I put: "|") : `if counting > 1|:`

Comment: can it be just an indentation issue?? I tried many variants but didn't solve anything

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an indentation issue. What I observe within your code is that the following code lines (the `if` blocks )try to access variable `name` and `top` which are defined within the `for` loop even though they are actually out of the `for` loop.

Indent these statements so that they fall within the `for` loop. Let us know if this works

```
if counting > 0:
    counting = counting + 1
    cheese = bcoords[i]*AT
    output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, cheese/(1-top))

if counting > 1:
    counting = counting + 1
    meat = bcoords[i]*AT
    output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, meat/(1-top-cheese))    

if counting > 2:
    counting = counting + 1
    bread = bcoords[i]*AT
    output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bread/(1-top-cheese-meat))

if counting > 3:
    output.write('\n')
    counting = 0
```

Comment: mmm.... I tried to improve as you said (see the edit of (2) above), but it still doesn't works, there's still a syntax error, but not at the same place... I don't get it

Comment: Hi, this works now but there's another error, please see below

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 `(` and only 2 `)` on the line before

So Python is effectively parsing it like this

```
output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, cheese/(1-top)) if counting > 1:...
```

and `if` is obviously a syntax error in there

Comment: Well, you've got a bunch of those to fix. Then the error message will be different, so you'll need to tell us what the next problem is.

Comment: OMG I forgot one... such a simple problem! Thanks, there's still a problem, plz see my post below